# TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target -- array reduce function signature

Tags: typescript

Here's my function signature:

```
export type ReduceCallback<TVal,TAcc> 
    = (accumulator: TAcc, currentValue: TVal, currentIndex: number, array: TVal[]) => TAcc


export function reduceArray<TVal,TAcc>(
    iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
    callback: ReduceCallback<TVal,TAcc>,
    initialValue: TAcc
): TAcc;
export function reduceArray<TVal>(
    iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
    callback: ReduceCallback<TVal,TVal>,
    initialValue?: TVal
): TVal {
    let arr = toArrayStrict(iterable);
    if(initialValue === undefined) {
        return arr.reduce(callback); // 2nd arg has to be fully omitted
    }
    return arr.reduce(callback, initialValue);
}
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
reduceArray([0,1,2,3], (acc, val) => acc + val)
```

`tsc` is complaining:

> TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

But I can't figure out why. My call should match the 2nd function signature, no? I've omitted `initialValue` in my call, so it should have no choice but to match the 2nd signature.

`[0,1,2,3]` is an `Iterable<number>`, `ReduceCallback` ought to be using `ReduceCallback<number,number>` which means `acc` and `val` are numbers.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the overloading syntax a little wrong. For overloads, you need a declaration for *each specific overload*. The actual function header doesn't count as a declaration. That means in your case you unfortunately have to specify the function header twice:

```
// because I don't know what toArrayStrict is
declare function toArrayStrict<T>(it: Iterable<T>): T[];

export type ReduceCallback<TVal, TAcc> 
    = (accumulator: TAcc, currentValue: TVal, currentIndex: number, array: TVal[]) => TAcc

export function reduceArray<TVal,TAcc>(
    iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
    callback: ReduceCallback<TVal,TAcc>,
    initialValue: TAcc
): TAcc;
// here we declare the second overload, which is just a duplicate of the actual function header
export function reduceArray<TVal>(
    iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
    callback: ReduceCallback<TVal, TVal>,
    initialValue?: TVal
): TVal;
export function reduceArray<TVal>(
    iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
    callback: ReduceCallback<TVal,TVal>,
    initialValue?: TVal
): TVal {
    let arr = toArrayStrict(iterable);
    if(initialValue === undefined) {
        return arr.reduce(callback); // 2nd arg has to be fully omitted
    }
    return arr.reduce(callback, initialValue);
}
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html (at the bottom)

Comment: Ohhh! So it's matching the "first overload" because there really is only one overload/signature in my version? Got it. That clears things up, thank you!

Comment: Yep! Looks like you got it. The general reasoning is that sometimes the actual function header needs to have a weird combination of union and intersection and optional types to support the overloads so it merits having it be separate from the declarations. However, you are in a case where it is indeed kind of weird to just duplicate your header to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.  Firstly, when you're calling reduceArray it's trying to use the first overload because of the typings where initialValue is non-optional.  Secondly, the overload of Array.reduce() you're looking for has a non-optional second parameter.

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, 
          currentIndex: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => U, initialValue: U): U;
```

The method should handle figuring out the "first pass" value automatically, so I've simplified that section.  I also replaced `toArrayStrict()` with `Array.from()` since I couldn't figure out what that method was, but it seemed to return an Array type.

```
export type ReduceCallback<TVal, TAcc> = (accumulator: TAcc, currentValue: TVal, currentIndex: number, array: Array<TVal>) => TAcc

export function reduceArray<TVal, TAcc>(
           iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
           callback: ReduceCallback<TVal, TAcc>,
           initialValue?: TAcc
       ): TAcc;
export function reduceArray<TVal>(
           iterable: Iterable<TVal>,
           callback: ReduceCallback<TVal, TVal>,
           initialValue?: TVal
       ): TVal
{
    let arr = Array.from(iterable);
    return arr.reduce(callback, initialValue);
}

let result = reduceArray([0, 1, 2, 3], (acc: number, val) => acc + val);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why would it use the first overload? In my first overload, `initiaValue` is non-optional, and I didn't supply the `initialValue` in my call -- therefore, it *can't* use that overload? I'm looking at the definitions in `lib.d.ts` and in the overload with `U`, `initialValue` is non-optional there too.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you on that one, but I did just discover that if you flip your overloads around it compiles with the one having a non-optional `initialValue`.  Trying to find documentation specifically about overloading with optional paremeters.  Can you post the overload you're referring to?  I don't see a `reduce<U>` with an optional `initialValue` parameter.

Comment: Ctrl+clicking `reduce` in PhpStorm turns up: `reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U`. That one is non-optional. The other is: `reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue?: T): T`

Comment: PS: y2bd gave a good explanation. The function signature immediately above the function body doesn't count as a declaration, so TypeScript doesn't use it. That's why swapping the order changes things.

Comment: In your case the latter overload isn't applicable because the typing of your currentValue (TVal) differs from the other variables (TAcc) (T = TVal, U = TAcc).